# how to make Rx requests faster dividing in separate threads?

Tags: android, rx-java2

For each data object I'm fetching more detail information and as a result it takes quite long time to have all datas then which I store in DB,
my question how it possible to organize `map(data->apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail)`  faster like dividing in separate threads

```
    apiIcaSeResource
    .fetchData("")
    .map(Datas::datas)
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMapIterable(datas->datas)
    .map(data - >apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail)
    .map(dataDetail->Pair.create(dataDetail,data))
    .toList()
    .map(store::insert())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Comment: just run it off the UI thread, since data operations seems sequential, I don't think adding multiple threads would help.

Comment: @Sarthak no I do but it slow it takes 3 min

Comment: you should check which operation is taking up most of the time, probably some api call?

Comment: it fetches the list of items and for each one(2000 items ) map(data - >apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail) . I know if I go with flatmap()  and divide it in separate threads could solve but don't know how.
I know the fetching data partly is solution but I could not do that because of api, I need to solve my task with existing api

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to use `flatMap` and apply to each `Observable` a Scheduler backed by an Executor thread-pool with fixed size. More precisely you have to use `computation()` scheduler.

```
apiIcaSeResource
    .fetchData("")
    .map(Datas::datas)
    .flatMapIterable(datas->datas)
    .flatMap(data -> apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail()
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                     .map(dataDetail -> Pair.create(dataDetail,data)))

    .toList()
    .map(store::insert())
```

If you don't do that, and you use for example `Schedulers.io()` you will create tons of Threads at the same time, and you'll get serious performance issues. Especially for your case, where you need to perform a lot of requests.

The problem with `Schedulers.computation()` is that, as the documentation says,

> Schedulers.computation() is recommended to perform blocking, IO-bound work on this
>   scheduler.

so it doesn't seem a good idea to use it for network calls.

So, another option is to use `Schedulers.io()` or `Schedulers.newThread()` specifying the limit of active thread for the `Observable`. For example, assuming that you want to have maximum 4 running network call you can do this:

```
final static int MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS = 4;

apiIcaSeResource
    .fetchData("")
    .map(Datas::datas)
    .flatMapIterable(datas->datas)
    .flatMap(data -> apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail()
                     .map(dataDetail -> Pair.create(dataDetail,data))
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS)
    .toList()
    .map(store::insert())
```

Another performance improvement that you probably can do, is to batch your data retrieved from the second service, using for example the `buffer()` operator. In this way you will insert multiple rows at time. Note that I don't expect this to be the bottleneck of the flow, because network operation are for sure slower, but it can still be a good improvement in my opinion.

Comment: on line flatMap (data->fetchDataDetail().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())) I have such problem ,
//no instances of type variables R exist so that Single<DataDetail> conforms to Publisher<? extends R>

Comment: But, as I said later on in the post, I think that the second one is a better approach, because it allows you to use a different scheduler other then computation() that shouldn't be used for io operations.

Comment: Sorry I don't see difference in flatMap part, I have the same problem,
I'll use the second approach and it's the same in that case as well

Comment: I removed `.toFlowable()` ,because your `apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail()` returns an `Observable`

Comment: I see but now it could not resolve flatMapIterable(datas->datas)

Comment: I don't know what are returning your functions.

Comment: Single<Datas> fetchData()
Single<DataDetail>fetchDataDetail()

Comment: Then apply `.toObservable()` after that: `getchDataDetail().toObservable()`

Comment: I'm moving forward step by step I changed what you mentioned but in Pair.create(dataDetail,data ) get "data is not resolved"

Comment: I didn't check all details of your implementation, I just added the part for solving your issue about having multiple threads for optimizing the work. Anyway the second `flatMap` should work only on the data received directly from the up stream, so you can remove your map and change your `fetchDataDetail` in a way that returns your Pair directly. (because I guess you are passing as input the `Data` to it)

Comment: Thanks
in flatMap I'm doing call to backend(fetchDataDetail), you mean add map in flatMap() and getting Pair<Data,DataDetail>as  a result of flatMap ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149115/discussion-between-gvillani82-and-a-a-i-a).

Comment: Hello, 
sorry for late response,
I have just checked, and see there is No speed difference it takes 3 min with previous solution as well, I tried Schedulers.computation()
and I could not find  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS) where MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS are defined.

Comment: Look carefully: `MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS` is not the second parameter of the `subscribeOn()`, but it is the second parameter of `flatMap`, as you can see [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20int))

Comment: Thanks
yes I see, but it doesn't make difference in speed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Any useful source that I can read concerning multithreading with flatmap() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThreadPoolExecutor to easily manage multiple threads and work distribution.
The ThreadPoolExecutor manages thread creation and termination as needed.

It can look quite intimidating at first glance but it really is rather simple when you take 10 minutes to read about it.

**Custom pool constructor looks something like this:**

```
Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
     int corePoolSize,
     int maximumPoolSize,
     long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
     BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
     ThreadFactory threadFactory,
     RejectedExecutionHandler handler
);
```

**And then:**

```
executor.execute(runnable);
```

You can also use built-in executors.

You can read more about it here: [ThreadPoolExecutor on the Android developers site](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just perform each `fetchDataDetail` in a new thread. You will need to change `map` for `flatMap`

```
apiIcaSeResource
    .fetchData("")
    .map(Datas::datas)
    .toFlowable()
    .flatMapIterable(datas->datas)
    .flatMap(data - >apiIcaSeResource.fetchDataDetail()
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())     // Perform each operation in a separate thread
    .map(dataDetail->Pair.create(dataDetail,data))
    .toList()
    .map(store::insert())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Comment: but for toList() it shows could not resolve method toList() .
How can I overcome this part?

Comment: Just copied your code and added one single line. Did it worked before?

Comment: Yes .it was working, I think it because of flatmap ()